# Get Country/Region Information from ExchangeUser Object

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook Interop application and I need to get the country / region entry from an exchange user object. It is not available through the public properties, is there any way to get it anyways?

```
ExchangeUser entry = OutlookManager.Instance.GetAddressBookEntry(mail.SenderName, mail.SenderAddress);

if (entry != null)
{
    var licensee = new Licensee();
    licensee.City = entry.City;
    licensee.Company = entry.CompanyName;
    //todo get country
    licensee.Country = ???
    licensee.Department = entry.Department;
    licensee.FirstName = entry.FirstName;
    licensee.LastName = entry.LastName;
    licensee.OutlookDisplayName = entry.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ExchangeUser.PropertyAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._exchangeuser.propertyaccessor.aspx) to retrieve the **Country** property. You need a try/catch in case the property isn't present. See [source reference](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/data-from-outlook) and available [Mail User Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446002.aspx).

```
try { 
    licensee.Country = entry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A26001E");
}
catch { licensee.Country = ""; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Funny thing is that this throws a COM Exception though the Region/Country field is present if I look at the address book entry through Outlook.

Comment: Where does the country/region show up under the address book entry in Outlook? There are multiple country/region fields. It could be PR_COUNTRY, PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, PR_HOME_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, or PR_OTHER_ADDRESS_COUNTRY. Refer to [Mail User Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446002.aspx) to determine which property tag (*proptag*) to retrieve.

Comment: It shows up in 'General' and I already tried all these properties, none worked unfortunately.

Comment: What property does it appear under when you click "All Fields" under the Show ribbon tab?